# STUFF and For XML path in Oracle11g query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here is a sample data: from this table ID is checked with stringvalue if stringvalue contains or equals with ID it gets the code based on the condition satisfied. if there are atleast 1 satisfied condtion the query will concatenates whatever the value of the code and place it under newcode.

```
   Scenario 1
    ID            CODE     VALUE               Newcode
    4           42                              44,45
    4           43                              44,45
    4           44         2,4,6                44,45
    4           45         2,4,6                44,45

Scenario 2

ID        CODE         VALUE                Newcode
4           42                     44
4           43                     44
4           44         4           44
4           45         3           44
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `list_agg`:

```
select sub.mainid, list_agg(cast(sub_code as nvarchar(100)), ',')
from ENPTREEATTRS SUB 
WHERE SUB.CODE in ('42','43','44','45') and
      SUB.STRINGVALUE LIKE '%'||cast(id as nvarchar(100))||'%'
group by sub.mainid
```

By the way, you shouldn't use `convert(nvarchar, id)` in SQL Server.  You should always provide a length, such as `convert(nvarchar(100), id)`.

Comment: getting an missing right parenthesis but i've checked it is complete.

Comment: @Rogbi . . . Well, this query isn't exactly the same, because of the correlation in the `where` clause.  But then again, the original query wan't a complete query.  This just shows the strategy for solving the problem, but its not a complete query.

Comment: I think this doesnt work for me. the sql query that I posted is only on select statement and I have lots of table to be joined in the main FROM statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, you should be able to use a subquery to get the list data and then join that back to your table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ID,
  CODE,
  ATTRSTRINGVALUE,
  SUB.Newcode
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN tabel2 b 
  ON a.MainID = b.mainID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SUB.MainID, 
    list_agg(cast(SUB.CODE as nvarchar2(50)), ',') as Newcode
  FROM ENPTREEATTRS SUB 
  WHERE SUB.CODE in ('42','43','44','45')
    AND SUB.STRINGVALUE LIKE '%'||cast(ID as nvarchar2(50))||'%'
  GROUP BY SUB.MainID
) SUB
  ON SUB.MainID = A.MainID
```

Edit #1 after your new query that you posted you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ID,
  CODE,
  ATTRSTRINGVALUE,
  SUB.Newcode
FROM ENPBATREE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN enptreeattrs B on A.MainID = B.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPTREEATTRS B1 on B.MainID = B1.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPTREEATTRS B2 on B1.MainID = B2.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPENTRYACCESSUSERSROLES D on B2.MainID = D.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPENTRYACCESSLIST F on D.USERNAME = F.USERNAME
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SUB.MainID, 
    list_agg(cast(SUB.CODE as nvarchar2(50)), ',') as Newcode
  FROM ENPTREEATTRS SUB 
  WHERE SUB.CODE in ('42','43','44','45')
    AND SUB.STRINGVALUE LIKE '%'||cast(ID as nvarchar2(50))||'%'
  GROUP BY SUB.MainID
) SUB
  ON SUB.MainID = A.MainID
```

You might be able to perform this without a subquery:

```
SELECT
  A.TREEENTRYID,
  F.accessid,
  b1.ATTRID,
  b1.attrstringvalue,
  list_agg(cast(SUB.ATTRID as nvarchar2(50)), ',') as Newcode
FROM ENPBATREE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN enptreeattrs B on A.TREEENTRYID  = B.TREEENTRYID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPTREEATTRS B1 on B.TREEENTRYID = B1.TREEENTRYID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPTREEATTRS B2 on B1.TREEENTRYID = B2.TREEENTRYID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPENTRYACCESSUSERSROLES D on B2.TREEENTRYID = D.TREEENTRYID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPENTRYACCESSLIST F on D.USERNAME = F.USERNAME
LEFT JOIN enptreeattrs SUB 
  ON SUB.MainID = A.MainID
WHERE SUB.ATTRID in ('42','43','44','45')
  AND SUB.ATTRSTRINGVALUE LIKE '%'||cast(F.ACCESSID as nvarchar2(50))||'%'
GROUP BY A.TREEENTRYID, F.ACCESSID, 
  b1.ATTRID, b1.attrstringvalue;
```

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  CODE,
  ATTRSTRINGVALUE,
  list_agg(cast(SUB.CODE as nvarchar2(50)), ',') as Newcode
FROM ENPBATREE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN enptreeattrs B on A.MainID = B.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPTREEATTRS B1 on B.MainID = B1.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPTREEATTRS B2 on B1.MainID = B2.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPENTRYACCESSUSERSROLES D on B2.MainID = D.MainID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENPENTRYACCESSLIST F on D.USERNAME = F.USERNAME
LEFT JOIN ENPTREEATTRS SUB 
  ON SUB.MainID = A.MainID
WHERE SUB.CODE in ('42','43','44','45')
  AND SUB.STRINGVALUE LIKE '%'||cast(ID as nvarchar2(50))||'%'
GROUP BY ID, CODE, ATTRSTRINGVALUE
```

Comment: just update the joins and i can't get to where to put the sub query on my oracle query?

Comment: I'm having an error F.ID invalid identifier on "AND SUB.STRINGVALUE LIKE '%'||cast(ID as nvarchar2(50))||'%'"

Comment: @Rogbi Where does the `ID` value come from?  What table?

Comment: from ENPENTRYACCESSLIST sorry for not updating the query. i NEED F.ID which outputs the ID from the scenarios.

Comment: error "missing keyword" i've update the question and naming of the columns to be clear. did i miss something on your update?

Comment: @Rogbi see my latest edit. Any items in the `SELECT` list must appear in the group by is they are not in the aggregate function.

Comment: Error at Line: 14 Column: 1 still missing keyword. :(

Comment: error again ORA-00904: "LIST_AGG": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Rogbi I am not sure what the error is from.  Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4) with your tables and some sample data?